# Upload file from C# winforms app to C# asp.net core mvc web app with azure auth and request token

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, winforms

Two parts: 
1. c# winforms app
2. c# asp.net core mvc web app

The web app has a controller action which accepts a file upload via. post request.

The desktop app needs to send a file the the web app action url without the user's help.

This would be simple for me, but the web app requires all requests to come from an azure authorized oauth.
And, the action requires the validation token as well.

I decided to use the webbrowser control instead of a pure httpwebrequest figuring this would take care of the azure auth part. And, it does, that part is working.

Next, I make the 'get' request and successfully get the form from the web app, token present, input element of 'file' type ready to take a file.

Then, I attempt to push the file value to the element.

Finally, I invoke a 'submit' call which successfully hits the web app's action on the controller,token verifies but the file is not there... it did not set the value on the input element in the prior step c# winform.

So, my second approach to get the file into the webbrowser control for sending involved using the .Navigate() method which features a parameter where we can include request headers.  I built the request header to include the file data.

Again, it navigates, the web app controller posts the request, but it fails because the token is not present as I do not know how to include that and am beginning to give up the the entire webbrowser control approach as it seems clunky.

If I could use a pure httpwebrequest that would be preferred but don't know how to build the entire request so it includes the necessary requirements for the azure auth and the validation token.

If I can make work what I have so far that would be fine, too.

Or, if anyone can suggest a better approach that would also be great.

Thanks.

HERE IS THE HTML FORM

```
<form id="frm2Upload" asp-action="UploadCompletions" asp- 
controller="CutStations" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="form-group col-lg-2">
    <input type="file" accept=".xml" id="formFile" name="formFile" class="control-label text-info" value="" />
    <br />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="fa fa-cloud-upload-alt"></span> Upload File</button>
</div> </form>
```

DESKTOP APP SETTING FILE IN WEB BROWSER HTML DOC

```
    public void Submit(string filepath)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement htmlElement_InputFile = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("formFile");
        htmlElement_InputFile.SetAttribute("value", filepath);
        form.InvokeMember("submit");
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't a different endpoint (on the server app), geared for a non-browser request (e.g. desktop) be an option (of course with its own authentication mechanisms)? Instead of mocking things? The protections are there, specifically geared to challenge what you (or anyone else for that matter) are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for responding!  I will take a look at that, didn't think of that as I am just not familiar with how that request would work but certain intrigued. As long as I could specify some un/pw and have some level of security as it will be posting data that will ultimately be saved in the database that would be great.

Comment: You could think of signing payloads from the client (using some shared secret between client and server) so you know it's from an "authorized client" (not user). If that's not enough, then you can add user auth as well (windows app login screen talking to your server an verifying un/pw). Hth

Comment: Thanks, EdSF, I went with your suggestion and is working great!!! Soooo much cleaner!   I used approach from the guy at this link: [link-Brian Grinstead](https://briangrinstead.com/blog/multipart-form-post-in-c/).  That combined with some simple challenge/password encryption and all is working...secure enough for what I am using it for and can change the security combination on both ends at any time. Thanks, again.